# How configure proxy in gradle graalvm plugin for Spring Native compile with Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, proxy, graalvm, spring-native

I try to build Spring native (Spring boot 3) behind an enterprise proxy.
I use gradle and gradle graalvm plugin (id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.18')

I use gradle-7.6 (with Oracle jdk-17.0.6) and graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.1

I allready configure this in gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=****
systemProp.http.proxyPort=****
systemProp.https.proxyHost=****
systemProp.https.proxyPort=****
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\\Windows\\win.ini
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\\Windows\\win.ini -Dhttp.proxyHost=**** -Dhttp.proxyPort=**** -Dhttps.proxyHost=**** -Dhttps.proxyPort=****
```

without expected result

I'm looking for right proxy config args in build.gradle for

```
graalvmNative {
   ...
}
```

I currently get in nativeCompile Task :

```
Error downloading component catalog from https://www.graalvm.org/component-catalog/v2/graal-updater-component-catalog-java17.properties: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```